# Sort an array within an array based on id

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have this JSON code being stored in Core data:

```
{  
   "success":1,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "activity_id":2,
         "datetime":1501932600,
         "athlete":{  
            "athlete_id":1,
            "first_name":"Bram",
            "last_name":"N"
         },
         "comments":[  
            {  
               "comment_id":1,
               "athlete":{  
                  "athlete_id":1,
                  "first_name":"Bram",
                  "last_name":"N"
               },
               "timestamp":1501876800,
               "message":"Good job!"
            },
            {  
               "comment_id":3,
               "athlete":{  
                  "athlete_id":1,
                  "first_name":"Bram",
                  "last_name":"N"
               },
               "timestamp":1501876800,
               "message":"Awesome"
            }
         ],
         "goals":[  
            {  
               "goal_id":1,
               "sport_name":"Running",
               "step":1,
               "goal_name":"Duration",
               "amount":30,
               "data_displayed":{  
                  "data_displayed_id":1,
                  "top_left":"Duration",
                  "top_right":"Distance",
                  "bot_left":"Heartrate",
                  "bot_right":"Pace"
               },
               "dataset":{  
                  "dataset_id":1,
                  "duration":63,
                  "distance":11,
                  "calories":309,
                  "steps":5048,
                  "pace_min":4,
                  "pace_max":5,
                  "pace_avg":5,
                  "heartrate_min":90,
                  "heartrate_max":190,
                  "heartrate_avg":143,
                  "elevation":0,
                  "decrease":0
               },
               "locations":[  
                  {  
                     "location_id":1,
                     "latitude":50,
                     "longitude":50,
                     "timestamp":1501853400
                  },
                  {  
                     "location_id":2,
                     "latitude":50,
                     "longitude":51,
                     "timestamp":1501853700
                  }
               ],
               "splits_distance":[  
                  {  
                     "splits_distance_id":1,
                     "distance":1,
                     "duration":4
                  },
                  {  
                     "splits_distance_id":2,
                     "distance":2,
                     "duration":5
                  }
               ],
               "splits_duration":[  
                  {  
                     "splits_duration_id":1,
                     "duration":5,
                     "distance":0.87
                  },
                  {  
                     "splits_duration_id":2,
                     "duration":10,
                     "distance":1.75
                  }
               ],
               "graph_values":[  
                  {  
                     "graph_value_id":1,
                     "timestamp":1501853400,
                     "distance":0,
                     "calories":0,
                     "steps":0,
                     "heartrate":0,
                     "pace":0,
                     "elevation":0
                  },
                  {  
                     "graph_value_id":2,
                     "timestamp":1501853700,
                     "distance":1.1,
                     "calories":50,
                     "steps":105,
                     "heartrate":132,
                     "pace":4.3,
                     "elevation":10
                  },
                  {  
                     "graph_value_id":7,
                     "timestamp":1501854000,
                     "distance":1.8,
                     "calories":142,
                     "steps":264,
                     "heartrate":154,
                     "pace":4.8,
                     "elevation":8
                  },
                  {  
                     "graph_value_id":8,
                     "timestamp":1501854300,
                     "distance":2.6,
                     "calories":209,
                     "steps":402,
                     "heartrate":143,
                     "pace":5.3,
                     "elevation":15
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "images":[  
            {  
               "image_id":1,
               "image_url":"www.trimeter.be\/image1"
            }
         ],
         "likes":[  
            {  
               "like_id":1,
               "athlete":{  
                  "athlete_id":1,
                  "first_name":"Bram",
                  "last_name":"N"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "activity_id":3,
         "datetime":1502137043,
         "athlete":{  
            "athlete_id":1,
            "first_name":"Bram",
            "last_name":"N"
         },
         "comments":[  
            {  
               "comment_id":4,
               "athlete":{  
                  "athlete_id":1,
                  "first_name":"Bram",
                  "last_name":"N"
               },
               "timestamp":1502149774,
               "message":"Test message, please ignore"
            }
         ],
         "goals":[  
            {  
               "goal_id":2,
               "sport_name":"Swimming",
               "step":1,
               "goal_name":"Distance",
               "amount":1500,
               "data_displayed":{  
                  "data_displayed_id":3,
                  "top_left":"Dit",
                  "top_right":"Is",
                  "bot_left":"Iets",
                  "bot_right":"Anders"
               },
               "dataset":{  
                  "dataset_id":2,
                  "duration":2,
                  "distance":2,
                  "calories":2,
                  "steps":2,
                  "pace_min":2,
                  "pace_max":2,
                  "pace_avg":2,
                  "heartrate_min":2,
                  "heartrate_max":2,
                  "heartrate_avg":2,
                  "elevation":2,
                  "decrease":2
               },
               "locations":[  

               ],
               "splits_distance":[  

               ],
               "splits_duration":[  

               ],
               "graph_values":[  

               ]
            },
            {  
               "goal_id":3,
               "sport_name":"Cycling",
               "step":2,
               "goal_name":"Distance",
               "amount":40000,
               "data_displayed":{  
                  "data_displayed_id":2,
                  "top_left":"1",
                  "top_right":"2",
                  "bot_left":"3",
                  "bot_right":"4"
               },
               "dataset":{  
                  "dataset_id":3,
                  "duration":3,
                  "distance":3,
                  "calories":3,
                  "steps":3,
                  "pace_min":3,
                  "pace_max":3,
                  "pace_avg":3,
                  "heartrate_min":3,
                  "heartrate_max":3,
                  "heartrate_avg":3,
                  "elevation":3,
                  "decrease":3
               },
               "locations":[  

               ],
               "splits_distance":[  

               ],
               "splits_duration":[  

               ],
               "graph_values":[  

               ]
            },
            {  
               "goal_id":4,
               "sport_name":"Running",
               "step":3,
               "goal_name":"Distance",
               "amount":10000,
               "data_displayed":{  
                  "data_displayed_id":4,
                  "top_left":"1234",
                  "top_right":"5678",
                  "bot_left":"4321",
                  "bot_right":"8765"
               },
               "dataset":{  
                  "dataset_id":4,
                  "duration":4,
                  "distance":4,
                  "calories":4,
                  "steps":4,
                  "pace_min":4,
                  "pace_max":4,
                  "pace_avg":4,
                  "heartrate_min":4,
                  "heartrate_max":4,
                  "heartrate_avg":4,
                  "elevation":4,
                  "decrease":4
               },
               "locations":[  

               ],
               "splits_distance":[  

               ],
               "splits_duration":[  

               ],
               "graph_values":[  

               ]
            }
         ],
         "images":[  
            {  
               "image_id":2,
               "image_url":"www.trimeter.be\/image2"
            }
         ],
         "likes":[  

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

After the data is stored in Core Data I fetch all the items and put them in an array to be used afterwards. 
Since the items don't get saved in order I sort them myself by their timestamp using this in the didSet of the array:

```
allActivitiesArray = allActivitiesArray.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp > $1.timestamp })
```

Now I also need to sort the goals and comments, how would I go about that? Can I somehow do this with the above line as well?

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
for activity in allActivitiesArray {
    var allGoals = activity.goals?.allObjects
    allGoals = allGoals?.sorted(by: { ($0 as! Goal).id < ($1 as! Goal).id } )
}
```

And then assigning the sorted goals back to the activity but it won't let me because I'd be assigning [Any] to an NSSet so I'm a bit lost here.

Any help/explanation is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is every line of these pages of JSON essential to this question?

Comment: Are you expecting us to write the code to parse that JSON, just to get some sample data to work with? No thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using [NSSortDescriptors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssortdescriptor) in your Core Data fetch request?

Comment: @meaning-matters No, but I didn't think it would hurt;

Comment: @Alexander Not at all, but a push in the direction of what I could use would be helpful

Comment: @mohak I didn't come across that, I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: It makes the people you're asking for help wade through pages of useless stuff. You're wasting other people's time and I think that hurts them.

Comment: Show the declaration of `allActivitiesArray`. If it is an Array of your custom type, show the definition the custom type. Without such info, your JSON just confuses readers and provides no clue to solve your issue. It really hurts readers.

Comment: @Bram-N Well we can't even give a "push in the direction" if we don't have a way to play around with this data and test our code.

Comment: I see, sorry! I thought there was a general function/something that would solve this. I've now solved it by creating an extension to my activity that sorts the goals and just call that whenever I need them.